# PyCharm type hinting return types

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't get typing hinting for return types to generate any warnings. For example the following code generates no warnings:

```
def foo():
    """
    :rtype : bool
    """
    return "bar"    # Returning wrong type

x, y = foo()        # Incorrectly expecting tuple
```

Do return types generate warnings, or are they only used for code completion? Type warnings when using type hinting for function parameters is working as expected. Python is 2.7, PyCharm is 4.5.3.

Comment: I believe it's only for code completion.

Comment: You miss warnings. Where should these warnings be emitted? Should python emit them? Or do you want pyCharm to emit them?

Comment: @f.rodrigues - Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3):

You can use `->` to hint the return type like this:

```
def hello(name: str) -> str:
    return 'hello '+name
```

Type hints are just *hints* that help IDE. Those types are not enforced. You can add a hint for a variable as `str` and set an `int` to it like this:

```py
a:str = 'variable hinted as str'
a = 5  # See, we can set an int
```

PyCharm will warn you but you will still be able to run the code. Because those are just hints. Python is not a type strict language. Instead, it employs dynamic typing.

Answer (score 0):

Return types are only used for code completion, what you've done has thoroughly confused PyCharm as to what you actually want to return.

Furthermore, `x,y = <string>` is valid if string is 2 characters long, so your last statement is not an invalid one.

```
In[3]: x, y = "ac"
In[4]: x
Out[4]: 'a'
In[5]: y
Out[5]: 'c'
```